# Statistical significance level of ML classification Baseline results in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I'm using scikit-learn to classify data to 2  different labels. After I choose one of my classification results as my baseline, I want to compare future results to this baseline (in python).
How can I see which results are improvements comparing to a baseline result with a 95% confidence interval, when my baseline result is a single Integer value?

Comment: This question seems a little bit too broad for me. Can you add some code and describe more precisely what you are aiming ?

Comment: I have a dictionary of values that represent the percentage of the classification, and I choose it as my Baseline (for example ```{'SVC': 84.7, 'RNN': 85.36}```). 
After running again the classification with different parameters I want to know if the new result is better in the statistical significance of at least 0.05 or lower then the baseline in at least 0.05, for each ML model (SVC and RNN in this example).

Comment: So the fact that your percentages come from classification ML algorithm is not relevant right ? All you need is to know if two empirical percentages can be considered different with enough statistical significance ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you need is a Student t-test for proportions. I could not find a very good explanation online on how to do it, but this link should be enough for you to understand if you have some prior knowledge on statistical tests : https://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx

Comment: As far as I know and from what I can understand from this article the T-Test is cant work if I only have a sample in length of one. In my case, I only want to compare single value to single value using some confidence interval, and not set of values compared to another set.
Is that even possible?

Comment: You don't need the whole sample, you just need to know its size (how many objects to classify)